# Should ImageView Bitmap resizing be done in asyncTask? android

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, android-asynctask, android-imageview

In my application I have imageUri(from gallery photos) and I want to scale the photo to show the user in imageView. Should I scale image in an asyncTask?

Extra : if you have any information about scaling jpg simple and fast way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your use-case and you application's structure.
Generally, decoding a bitmap from file should NOT be done on the UI thread. Scaling an existing Bitmap is not as heavy operation as decoding it from file, so if its only one image I guess you could do it on UI thread.